# Formatting data in a modal html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a web application and i want to show some data in a modal, but i want it to have the following format:

```
Name: John
ID: 7
```

being John and the number 7 the data itself.

The problem is that i'm only able to achieve this using input boxes, like this:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group modal-body">
        <label for="tableName" class="control-label">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tableName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group modal-body">
        <label for="tableID" class="control-label">ID:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tableID">
    </div>
</form>
```

How can i do this, so i don't have the input boxes surrounding the data ?

Comment: for me your question is not clear. can you set up a jsFiddle or explain it better. I don' understand the real issue. You could replace input with any tag. what is issue in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `<span>` in the place of `<input>`

replace

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tableName">
```

with

```
<span>John(some dynamic data)</span>
```

maybe this is what you are asking...

Comment: Thanks! it was not what i was asking, but i was able to make it work with the span tag!

Comment: What did you asked exactly ?